# How to delete old data that was created by Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming, apache-spark-2.0

how can I delete old data created by Spark Structured Streaming (Spark 2.4.5)?

I have data on HDFS in parquet/avro format (**not Delta**), that is created by **Spark Structured Streaming** and partitioned by time (year,month,day of month,hour).

The data is created as following:

```
query = df.writeStream.format("avro").partitionBy("year", "month", "day", "hour").outputMode("append").option("checkpointLocation", "/data/avro.cp").start("/data/avro")
```

As result i have following  partition folder layout:

```
./year=2020/month=3/day=13/hour=12
./year=2020/month=3/day=13/hour=13
./year=2020/month=3/day=13/hour=14
./year=2020/month=3/day=13/hour=15
./year=2020/month=3/day=13/hour=16
```

How can I delete old data, for example older than year=2020,month=2,day=13,hour=14?

Just deleting relevant folders

```
./year=2020/month=3/day=13/hour=12
./year=2020/month=3/day=13/hour=13
```

throws an exception while reading batch dataframe from file-system:

```
df = spark.read.format("avro").load("/data/avro")
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/data/avro/year=2020/month=3/day=13/hour=12/part-00000-0cc84e65-3f49-4686-85e3-1ecf48952794.c000.avro does not exist
```

As I've figured out that is somehow related to `_spark_metadata` folder that is used by checkpoints.

Appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete that folder unless you delete it's corresponding checkpoint folders too. You are trying to delete the folder while the checkpoint still has knowledge of it, so that is why the error is occurring.

However, I really wouldn't recommend messing with the checkpoint folder unless necessary. If it's possible in your situation, I'd suggest instead moving your old data to different data storage types such as in AWS Standard -> Glacier.

Comment: So how do delete old data? For long term, Structured Streaming app creates a lot of data, and at some point very old data is not longer relevant and it just uses HDFS disk space.

Comment: @YuriiOleynikov Look here: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/22952

Comment: Thank you @Zack, but it's really strange that there's no solution of purging old data for 24/7 running Spark SS apps.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that I found solution/workaround.
The key concept is to use FileStreamSinkLog andn udpate it with SinkFileStatus with action set to `delete`:

1. load FileStreamSinkLog

   ```
    sinkLog = new FileStreamSinkLog(1, spark, full-path-to-spark-metadata-dir);
   ```
2. get latest SinkFileStatus

   ```
    Option<Tuple2<Object, SinkFileStatus[]>> latest = sinkLog.getLatest();
    long batchId = (long)latest.get()._1;
    SinkFileStatus[] fileStatuses = latest.get()._2;
   ```
3. delete old files
4. Add new new entry with `delete` action to `fileStatuses` array
5. write `batchId` log file back with updated `fileStatuses`

However this requires that structured streaming job be stopped.
So there's no solution for delete old files written by Spark Structured Streaming without stopping it.

Answer (score 0):

For your ease of copy/paste, here's a working code (scala) snippet as of spark 3.0.1.  Deletes one file and writes a new batch:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSinkLog

import scala.language.postfixOps
import scala.sys.process._
import scala.util.Try

        val sinkLog = new FileStreamSinkLog (
            1,
            spark,
            SPARK_METADATA_ROOT
        )
        val head = sinkLog.allFiles().head

        val deleteCommand = s"hadoop fs -rm ${head.path}"
        println (Try (deleteCommand ! processlogger).getOrElse(s""""$deleteCommand" failed""") )

        head.copy(action = FileStreamSinkLog.DELETE_ACTION)

        sinkLog
            .add (
                latestBatch.get._1+1,
                Array(head.copy(action = FileStreamSinkLog.DELETE_ACTION))
                )
```

Comment: yep, however as far as I know, this requires structured streaming be stopped

Answer (score 0):

For Spark 3.0.0 and above, it has been implemented.

- The original issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20568
- Configuration: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/FileStreamOptions.scala#L117

Basically it adds 3 strategy for committed files (ARCHIVE, DELETE, OFF) and allows just configure it.

Honestly, I have never tried it myself, but I see some answers here for Spark 3+ and it definitely worth mentioning.